# Three.js MultiplyVector3 Deprecated How to replace

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have a code, in three.js in console it says :

> DEPRECATED: Matrix4's .multiplyVector3() has been removed. Use vector.applyMatrix4( matrix ) or vector.applyProjection( matrix ) instead.

But I have no idea how to do such.

Here is my code:

```
 var rotation_matrixc = new THREE.Matrix4();
 rotation_matrixc.extractRotation(CHROMEboyPC.matrix);
 var cam_vectorc = new THREE.Vector3(    100 ,  30 ,  5);
 var   final_cam_vectorc = rotation_matrixc.multiplyVector3(cam_vectorc);
 camera.position.copy(CHROMEboy.position ).add(final_cam_vectorc   );
 camera.lookAt(CHROMEboy.position);
```

How to write equivalent code using suggested Methods.

Answer (score 6):

You use the opposite notation:

Use the vectors .applyMatrix3 or .applyMatrix4 function to rotate the vector

```
var final_cam_vectorc = cam_vectorc.applyMatrix4( rotation_matrixc );
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace multiplyVector3, simplify a follow method and clarify the previous answer a bit:

cameraOffset is a Vector containing the camera's relative positions to the followed.

"player" is the object being followed.  You may need to increase the offsets.

```
        var cameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 2.5);

        // modify it relative to the followed object
        var new_cam_position = cameraOffset.applyMatrix4( player.matrix );

        // copy the new position vector to the camera
        camera.position.copy(new_cam_position);

        // look at
        camera.lookAt(player.position);
```